# How to keep edit control from showing up when covered by another control?

Tags: c++, winapi, native

I have created an edit box and a listbox.  When they overlap, with the listbox on top, the mouse cursor changes to an I-Beam when it is over the part of the listbox that is covering part of the edit box and an outline of the edit box appears:

**BEFORE mouse over:**

[image: Before mouse over]

**AFTER mouse over:**

[image]

Code used to create the controls:

```
    HWND hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_EDIT, "xxx", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE| ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        50, 100, 200, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    HWND hList = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, _T(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
        70, 150, 200, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST_VIEW, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

I have tried fiddling with the x-order using SetWindowPos but it doesn't change the behaviour.  In any case, I think the control order creation should place the listbox above the edit control.

Why is it doing this and more importantly, how do I fix it so the edit stays covered?

To reproduce, create a win32 project in VS2015.  Add the above 2 lines to WM_CREATE along with the appropriate includes defines etc.  That's pretty much it.  The code below is without any items added to the `listview`.

UPDATE: By popular demand here is the complete code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project3.h"
#include <commctrl.h>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define IDC_MAIN_EDIT   140
#define ID_LIST_VIEW 143

#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WIN32PROJECT3, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT3));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WIN32PROJECT3));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WIN32PROJECT3);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWND hList = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTBOX, _T(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
        70, 150, 200, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST_VIEW, GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);

        HWND hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_EDIT, _T("xxx"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        50, 100, 200, 160, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um... Don't overlap the controls? A combobox is usually the way you combine an edit and a list.

Comment: Or use `ShowWindow()` to hide one control and show the other.

Comment: I don't want to hide any control.  Only stop the edit control from showing through controls that are on top of it.  The part of the edit that is not covered should still be visible.

Comment: It doesn't reproduce for me (Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015).  Are you handling mouse over or focus events for either of those children?

Comment: Not handling any mouse events.  Using windows 10 VS 2015

Comment: [mcve] probably needed. It would help also if the question matched the code. You describe a list box but create a list view.

Comment: Actually I don't think it would help at all if "the quesiton matched the code"  It doesn't matter if it's a listbox or a listview, the problem is the same. Will add more code so it can be verified.

Comment: Why won't you add a [mcve]? It doesn't help when the details are wrong because it erodes trust. You say you did X but it's clear you did Y. What else are you are you telling us that is wrong. Remove all doubt. Add a MCVE. Do you want help or not?

Comment: Please see above.  I have added all the code and how to reproduce.  I created a new c++ win32 project (VS2015) and only added the lines shown.

Comment: It would be easy to provide a complete program so that we can be sure we run the same code as you. Perhaps there's a problem in the code you did not include.

Comment: The "Minimal" part I take to mean only include relevant code sufficient to reproduce the issue.  Step one: create win32 project in VS2015.  Step two: Add the above lines.  Step three: Profit!  (Sorry). Run the program to see the issue verified. Unless Microsoft have included some dodgy code in their win32 project template, there isn't any reason to show it. It's basic boilerplate.

Comment: You forgot to mention step 0: Download and install Visual Studio 2015 (maybe with, maybe without an update, you aren't telling). Please provide a [mcve]. It needs to be both minimal as well as complete. There's no point pondering about code we cannot see.

Comment: Ok I surrender.  See complete code above.  I would really love to know if there is a fix for this or even it's just  just me it's happening to?

Comment: Specifying the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` [window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) on the control parent window seems like a good option.

Comment: @IInspectable that should be on the controls themselves, not the parent.

Comment: @IInspectable THANK YOU!  Please write it up as an answer so I can award it to you. Yeah should be on the children, not the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is caused by one control rendering into the client area of another control, as it's handling `WM_PAINT` messages.

To prevent this from happening, rendering needs to be clipped, so that it excludes regions that are occupied by other controls. Setting the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` [window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) on controls instructs the system to apply an appropriate clipping region:

> Clips child windows relative to each other; that is, when a particular child window receives a [**WM_PAINT**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx) message, the **WS_CLIPSIBLINGS** style clips all other overlapping child windows out of the region of the child window to be updated. If **WS_CLIPSIBLINGS** is not specified and child windows overlap, it is possible, when drawing within the client area of a child window, to draw within the client area of a neighboring child window.